# React functional app with Unhandled Rejection (RangeError): Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing my first form using reactjs using a functional app. I was able to make the form working and set some simple validations.

I prepared a function that will handle the submit form to backend. However, when I clicked the submit. It throws the following error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60d5h.png)

```
Unhandled Rejection (RangeError): Maximum call stack size exceeded
postUsers
src/pages/Users/create.js:29
  26 |     }
  27 | }
  28 | 
> 29 | const postUsers = async () => {
     | ^  30 |     let res = await postUsers(mobileCountryCode)
  31 |     
  32 |     console.log("postUsers.res:")
```

Can you guys please help me figure out what did I missed?

Thank you

Form.js

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import './Users.scss'
    
    const UsersCreate = (props) => {
    *emphasized text*
    const [mobileCountryCode, setmobileCountryCode] = useState("");
    const [mobileCountryCodeErr, setmobileCountryCodeErr] = useState({});

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("handleSubmit:")
        console.log(e)

        const isValid = formValidation()

        if (isValid) {
            console.log("Form Valid: Processing on Backend")
            console.log("mobileCountryCode: ", mobileCountryCode)
            postUsers()
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            console.log("Form Invalid: Please check form")
        }
    }

    const postUsers = async () => {
        let res = await postUsers(mobileCountryCode)
        
        console.log("postUsers.res:")
        console.log(res)
        
    }

    const formValidation = () => {
        const mobileCountryCodeErr = {}
        let isValid = true

        if (mobileCountryCode.trim().length != 2) {
            mobileCountryCodeErr.missingLength = "Mobile country code must be two (2) digits."
            isValid = false
        }

        setmobileCountryCodeErr(mobileCountryCodeErr)
        return isValid
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <h1 className="title">Users</h1>
            <h2 className="subtitle">Create New User</h2>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                <div className="field">
                    <label className="label">User Type</label>
                    <div className="control">
                        <div className="select">
                            <select>
                                <option>Admin</option>
                                <option>Manager</option>
                                <option>User</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="field">
                    <label className="label">Mobile Country Code</label>
                    <div className="control">
                        <input name="mobileCountryCode" className="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input"
                            value={mobileCountryCode}
                            onChange={e => setmobileCountryCode(e.target.value)} />
                    </div>
                    {Object.keys(mobileCountryCodeErr).map((key) => {
                        return <p className="help is-danger">{mobileCountryCodeErr[key]}</p>
                    })}
                </div>

                <div className="field">
                    <label className="label">Mobile Number</label>
                    <div className="control">
                        <input name="mobile_number" className="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="field is-grouped">
                    <div className="control">
                        <button className="button is-link" type="submit">Create New User</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="control">
                        <button className="button is-link is-light">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>



        </div>
    )
}

export default UsersCreate
```

postUsers.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const postUsers = async (mobileCountryCode, mobileNumber) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
            .post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST + "/users",
                {
                    mobile_country_code: mobileCountryCode,
                    mobile_number: mobileNumber,
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxx'
                    }
                },
            )
            .then(response => {
                console.log("handleSubmit.response:")
                console.log(response)
                resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error)
                console.log("login error", error);
                reject(error)
            });
    })
}

export default postUsers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like instead of calling `postUsers` from the `postUsers.js` file, `postUsers` is calling itself, which causes it to call itself and so on until the stack overflows.

Javascript is a dynamic language, and doesn't have function overloading as you'd expect from typed languages. This means if you have two functions with the same name, regardless of the number of parameters they expect, the last definition will override the previous ones.

Just change one of the functions' name to distinct them from one another (and don't forget to import it), that should solve the issue.

Comment: Oops, I never thought that could be a problem. Let me try that.